# Activerecord list distinct WITH count

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Resource Model with entries that can have the same resource name:

**Resource Model**

```
ID name
1  Item 1
2  Item 1
3  Item 2
4  Item 3
....
```

I would like to list distinct Resource.name with a count of the number of occurances of that resource in my view:

```
Item 1 (2)
Item 2 (1)
Item 3 (1)
```

Performance is my main concern since there is a lot already going on in the view since it's a dashboard.

I could probably do this by pulling all of the Resources and filtering in the view but that will be pretty heavy on page load times, does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with the combination of `group` and `count` methods:

```
Item.group(:name).count
>> ["Item 1" => 2, "Item 2" => 1, "Item 3" => 1]
```

Comment: Great, I also needed ID so amended what you said to: Item.group(:id, :name).count. I don't know if I'm accessing this in a clever way in the view, I'm doint it as follows: item[0][0] - id, item[0][1] - name, item[1] - count.  Seems a bit nasty!

Comment: Well, you can't group by the `ID`, as it is unique for every record. In the view you can do it like this: `items.each do |k,v|` iterates over the list, `k` is the name and `v` is the count value.